# django giving TypeError when using len() on a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I am programming a very simple application to store results of soccer matches, and I am stuck with the following problem. When running one of the unit tests, the following code:

```
listCompetition = Competition.objects.filter(compId=competitionId)
if len(listCompetition) == 0:
   #some code here
else:
   #some code here
```

gives the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\admin\workspace\project\src\bla\bla\module.py", line 222, in getMatches
   if len(listCompetition) == 0:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 82, in __len__
   self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 286, in iterator
   obj = model(*row[index_start:aggregate_start])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

However, if I substitute the first line of code by:

```
listCompetition = list(Competition.objects.filter(compId=competitionId))
```

then it works perfectly fine. Why does it behave in this strange way? How comes that Django is passing 4 parameters, if I have defined only two in the constructor of class Competition? If it helps, here is the model definition for class Competition:

```
class Competicion(MultiName):
   def __init__(self, canonicalName, compId):
      super(Competition, self).__init__(canonicalName, compId)

class MultiName(models.Model):
   entId = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=25); 
   canonicalName = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True);

   def __init__(self, canonicalName, entId=None):
      super(MultiName, self).__init__()
      self.canonicalName = canonicalName;
      self.entId = entId;
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's broken because you've broken the conventions in use by Django models when you overrode `__init__`. Why are you implementing `__init__` anyway? What you're implementing is… already implemented.

You seem to be making assumptions about how to use Django that are unfounded. I suggest you read the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) before proceeding.

To fix your code, change it to the following:

```
class Competition(MultiName):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "compId" in kwargs:
            kwargs["entId"] = kwargs.pop("compId")
        super(Competition, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MultiName(models.Model):
    entId = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=25); 
    canonicalName = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True);
```

There's a lot of [great documentation for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/#the-model-layer) that covers this stuff.

Comment: Bradley: Shouldn't that be __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)?  Also, see my answer above: his bigger problem is not understanding that a Queryset is an iterator, not a list.

Comment: Yes absolutely, good catch. I'd say his bigger issue is overriding `__init__` in a way that makes it impossible for him to retrieve a model instance. `len()` vs `.count()` is really just a performance concern, both would work.

Comment: You're completely right, I should create my objects without overriding `__init__ `, calling `instance = Competition(canonicalName='name', entId='id')` would be much easier. My background is Java, and I was trying to do the things like in Java (fail), but now I realize that's not the way in Django. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 11):

Simple: in your first case, you're getting back a queryset object, not a list.  Querysets are Iterators.  List objects are also Iterators, but Iterators are not lists.

Django does this to optimize memory and performance: the database keeps the set, and Django reads the response one item at a time, each time you request an object from the queryset.  Using `list()` causes Django to read the entire response and pack it into a list object.  If the return set is very large, this can be problematic.

To know how big a queryset is, use the `Queryset.count()` method instead.

Comment: `len()` works on iterators… (try `len(xrange(10))`) -- but yes, using `.count()` is the correct method.

Comment: Yeah, but len() causes list coercion.  It's very poor form.  You're right, though, that his __init__() is incorrecty written, and totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of

```
if len(listCompetition) == 0:
```

use

```
if listCompetition.count() == 0:
```

or perhaps

```
if not listCompetition.exists():
```

Comment: His exception is from overriding `__init__` incorrectly. Sure using `.count()` will side step this problem, but as soon as he tries to retrieve a model instance the same exception will be raised.